# MVC C# Code in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

On a cshtml page in my View i easily get the URL to an action with thise line:

```
<h1>@Url.Action("NewComment", "Case")</h1>
```

And if I write this in Javascript:

```
<script>
    alert('@Url.Action("NewComment", "Case")');
</script>
```

It also comes up correct in the alert.

However my problem is that at the bottom of the page I have several other javascript beeing referenced like this:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/custom/SomeScript.js"></script>
```

And if I write `alert('@Url.Action("NewComment", "Case")');`

In that file. It just comes up as `@Url.Action("NewComment", "Case")` in the alert box.

So how come it doesn't work in this file?

In the same file I also have a click method with $.ajax({ method and the url is referenced like this: `url: '@Url.Action("NewComment","Case")',` and here it works fine again.

So how come it works here again? Is it something with that Ajax method is a Jquery Object??

---

The spesific problem I have is that I need to reference the URL.Action method i the Ajax call of a Jquery Datatable.

```
var table_comment= $('#comment_table').dataTable({
    "sDom": "<'dt-toolbar'>",
    ajax: {
        url: "/Case/NewComment/", //This works but want to change it to use URL Action
        url: '@Url.Action("NewComment", "Case")', //don't understand why this doesn't work
        type: "POST",
        data: {"id": Case_ID }
    },
```

Comment: you are writing above code in separate js file???

Comment: Yes. Ajax code that works fine with Url.Action is i a seperate JS file and the datatable code is also in a seperate JS file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a way better solution for this!

RazorJS :) Works perfect.

http://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorJS

Answer (score 3):

The reason that `@Url.Action("NewComment", "Case")` works in *.cshtml, is that it is rendered to HTML on the server by ASP.NET MVC. As for your *.js files, these are not transformed by ASP.NET MVC, so what you see is what you get.

Specifically, .cshtml files are [C# Razor templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Razor_view_engine), which get rendered by ASP.NET MVC to .html files.

As for your .js files, perhaps you could work around this by defining your URLs as global variables in your .cshtml, which you simply refer to in your .js files.

```
<script>
var newCommentUrl = '@Url.Action("NewComment", "Case")';
</script>
```

Comment: But how come this works: $.ajax({ url: '@Url.Action("NewComment","Case")' ... etc. This is also in a seperate JS file

Comment: @stibay I don't know. There shouldn't be any template transformation in .js files (because they aren't Razor templates), so I have no idea why `@Url.Action("NewComment","Case")` would be transformed.

Comment: Yea. That works actually. Defining the variable in javascript on the cshtml page and refer to it in the js. file :) Still wierd that the Ajax methods can access it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write Razor syntax inside separate js file because after all its Razor syntax `'@'` which only

Razor engine could interpret(and could be written inside .cshtml extension Pages only) and razor engine

convert it to appropriate HTML so that is why

in separate js file file when you write `alert("@Url.Action("NewComment", "Case")")` it comes as

`@Url.Action("NewComment", "Case")`

Answer (score 0):

You can't have razor syntax ( `@Url.Action` ) inside a linked JavaScript file - Visual Studio doesn't work like that.

As a solution, write out your variables in javaScript in your CSHTML file like so:

```
<script type="Text/javascript">
 var dataTableURL = '@Url.Action("NewComment","Case")';
</script>
```

And then underneath this reference your external javascript file

```
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MyJavaScriptFile.cs")' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And modify your javscript variable to use the above variable:

```
var table_comment= $('#comment_table').dataTable({
    "sDom": "<'dt-toolbar'>",
    ajax: {
        url:dataTableURL,
        type: "POST",
        data: {"id": Case_ID }
    },
```

Comment: Yea. This worked as aknuds1 suggested ;) Still think it's pretty funny that if I have a click method in an external JS file. F.ex like this: $(document).on("click", ".save-comment", function (e) { and this function runs $.ajax({ method I can reference the url parameter like this: url: '@Url.Action("NewComment","Case")' and it works perfect :)